# How to get a UIImage from a String with JSON data

Tags: ios, swift, api, uiimage, openweathermap

I am trying to load an icon image form the API `OpenWeatherMap`, and display it in an `ImageView`. I am trying to load it into the `imageView` '`iconImage`'. I have successfully loaded the `JSON` data for the location and humidity, as they are `Strings`, but the Icon data is also a `String` and I cannot get it to display as a `UIImage`.

**Code below:**

My JSON Structs below:

```
struct Coordinate : Decodable {
        let lat, lon : Double?
    }

    struct Weather : Decodable {
        var id : Int?
        var main, myDescription, icon : String?

        enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
            case id = "id"
            case main = "main"
            case icon = "icon"
            case myDescription = "description"
        }
    }

    struct Sys : Decodable {
        let type, id : Int?
    let sunrise, sunset : Date?
    let message : Double?
    let country : String?
}

struct Main : Decodable {
    let temp, tempMin, tempMax : Double?
    let pressure, humidity : Int?
}

struct Wind : Decodable {
    let speed : Double?
    let deg : Int?
}

struct MyWeather : Decodable {
    let coord : Coordinate?
    let cod, visibility, id : Int?
    let name : String?
    let base : String?
    let weather : [Weather]?
    let sys : Sys?
    let main : Main?
    let wind : Wind?
    let dt : Date?
}`enter code here`
```

View controller below:

```
  guard let APIUrl = URL(string: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + text +  "&appid=e7b2054dc37b1f464d912c00dd309595&units=Metric") else { return }
    //API KEY

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: APIUrl) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data else { return }


        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        //Decoder

        do {

if (self.iconImage != nil)
                {
                    if let gicon = weatherData.weather?.first?.icon {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.iconImage.image! =  gicon
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (self.LocationLabel != nil)
                {
                    if let gmain = weatherData.name {
                        print(gmain)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.LocationLabel.text! = "Current Weather in: " + String (gmain)
                        }
                    }
                }


                if (self.HumidityLabel != nil)
                {
                    if let ghumidity = weatherData.main?.humidity
                    {
                        print(ghumidity, "THIS IS HUMIDITY")
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.HumidityLabel.text! = String (ghumidity)
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Icon data is a url or what ? show your Icon data string .

Answer (score 0):

Icon is the id of the image , you need to append it to this url and load it

> http://openweathermap.org/img/w/10d.png  // here  ------  id = 10d

suppose you'll use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) , then do this

```
let urlStr = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/\(gicon).png"
self.iconImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:urlStr), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
```

See here in [Docs](https://openweathermap.org/weather-conditions)

Comment: I have tried implementing your method, and I am getting the error: 'Value of type 'UIImageView' has no member 'sd_setImageWithURL''

Comment: You need to download the image from the url , and for this add this pod https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage , then install it , after that import the library and the line will compile , anyway you can download the image with any other alternative , the idea was in having the url , if you don't hear about ios cocapods google it

Answer (score 0):

Use [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher)

It creates an extension in ImageView. You will use `self.imageview.kf.setImage(with: "url")`